# The closure of a countable union of sets

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Given $\left\{A_n\right\}$ an *ascending* sequence of sets in a metric space, I wonder under what conditions we can have
$$
\overline{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\overline{A_n}.
$$

1. If $A_n$ is closed for all $n$, the answer is NO. Consider $A_n = [\frac{1}{n},1] \subset \mathbb{R}$。
2. If $A_n$ is closed and convex, also NO, consider the same example.
3. If $A_n$ is closed and meager, No, consider $A_n= \left\{q_1,q_2,...,q_n\right\}$, where $q_i \in \mathbb{Q}$.

What about $A_n$ is closed, convex and meager? It seems not quite obvious for me. If NOT, what conditions should $A_n$ satisfy so that we have the nice property stated before?

Comment: If the family $(A_n)_n$ is locally finite, then
$\overline{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\overline{A_n}.
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\mathbb R^{2}$ the sets $A_n=[\frac  1 n ,1]\times \{0\}$ are closed convex and have empty interior. They don't satisfy the identity $$
\overline{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\overline{A_n}.
$$.

I don't think there is any useful simple condition which guarantees this identity.

Comment: $2$ dimensions would have been enough for this example.

Comment: @Jochen Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

The identity is equivalent to $\displaystyle\cup_{n=1}^\infty \overline{A_n}$ being closed.

There are examples, such as $A_n = \{0\}\cup\left[\frac{1}{n}, 1\right]$, but I don't think there is a general sufficient condition.